# Correct Self-Employment Forms for 1040

Tags: united-states, income-tax, self-employment, form-1040

Am I filing the correct forms with my 1040 to include my self-employment tax? Sole-proprietor with less than $5000 business expenses and profit less than $9000.

- 1040
- Schedule 1
- Schedule 4
- Schedule C-EZ
- Schedule SE Self-Employment Tax - taxpayer
- Schedule SE Self-Employment Tax Part B - taxpayer

Comment: You might also want the form (I think it's 8829) for business use of your home.  Read the instructions to see if you qualify.  If so, it can be a good deduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That basically looks right.

- [Form 1040](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1040) is the main tax return form.
- [Schedule C-EZ](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-schedule-c-ez-form-1040) has the revenue, expenses, and net profit from your business.  Since your expenses were less than $5000, you can use C-EZ instead of the full [Schedule C](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-schedule-c-form-1040) (assuming you also meet all the other C-EZ requirements).
- Schedule 1 is used to include the net profit from C-EZ into Form 1040.
- [Schedule SE](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-schedule-se-form-1040) is for the self-employment tax.  Section A is the "short schedule" and Section B is the "long schedule."  You need to look at the flowchart at the beginning of SE to determine which one you need to complete.
- Schedule 4 brings the self-employment tax from SE into Form 1040.

Of course, depending on your personal tax situation, there may be other forms you will also need to include with your tax return.